# VideoView problem in 2.1 Emulator of Android?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am using the code available here [VideoView Example](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2009/12/04/android-%E2%80%93-videomusic-player-sample-take-2/). This code runs properly on Android emulator 1.6 but not on 2.1.

In 2.1 it only plays the audio and not video. I have gone through several other threads where this issue has been mentioned. I will like to know whether this problem is limited to emulator only or the devices also have the same problem.

Regards

Sunil

Comment: The VideoView Example blog contains some hints in the comments. Seems to be a layout issue. Look at the last couple of comments. I would be surprised if the actual devices would behave differently, but can't give you an answer right now since I'm still waiting for the Android 2.1 update for my HTC Hero ;)

Answer (score 3):

Emulators will have great difficulty playing back video, due to speed. The emulator does not have hardware acceleration -- combine that with converting ARM opcodes to x86 on the fly, and the emulator cannot keep up. I have a quad-core 2.6GHz desktop, and I can only occasionally get the emulator to play back video.

IMHO, to work with video, you need a device.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. But if this emulator cannot play back the video properly then why 1.6 is able to everytime I try to play and 2.1 doesn't play even once. I will also try with 1.5 and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Try it in real android device,because emulator can not play video